# Convert from hours to minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert hours to minutes? For Example: I want convert `3:30` to minutes.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? date/time functions are different with any product

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `SELECT [Minutes] = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(TIME, '3:30'))`

Comment: @GarethD that should be the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

In MSSQL:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, '3:30')
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp